# Display Password Validation Rules in Registration form before Submitting

Tags: laravel, authentication, passwords, breeze

I'm new to Laravel and I just installed breeze on my project.

Everything works very well with breeze authentication and how it displays errors on sign up form after clicking the submit button.

But I would like the users to see what are the password rules (Like minimum length and so on) even before submitting.

**Is it Possible?! If yes, then how?!**

***Laravel v9.38.0 (PHP v8.1.6)***

Comment: you can read https://tallpad.com/series/inertiajs-laravel-misc/lessons/prevalidate-forms-in-inertiajs-and-laravel-applications

Comment: I guess you could "simply" edit the available auth components/views and add that information

Comment: There are at least a hall a dozen ways to accomplish this. As @brombeer stated, you could put the requirements on the page, under the password field, next to it, above it, in a help pop-up and so on. Alternatively, you could use JS (jQuery, Formvalidator, etc.) or Laravel Livewire, just depends on which way you want to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that in javascript.

You can also do real-time validation with Livewire. If you only use it for the password real-time check, you better go with some handmade JS.

Livewire doc: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation#real-time-validation